# Disable/block the logs sent from fluentd sidecar container to Log Explorer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, fluentd, sidecar

Holla amigos, In Google Cloud GKE I have 3 containers inside a pod. The first one is the application, the second is the istio-proxy sidecar, and the third one is the fluentd sidecar. The scenario is simple where I would like to block/stop the logs that are being sent from the fluentd container to log explorer (GCP logging console). In the meantime, I would still like my fluentd store the logs inside the pod, so that I can check the logs manually using gke exec command. Please let me know if it is possible....

Answer (score 0):

If your container is writing the logs at a specific path or on the Hostpath file system

you can use the **fluentd** to parse that specific application logs from path where the application container is writing. it depends on the application and your architecture.

You can also use the `exclude_path` to exclude

Here sharing one ref example for **fluentd** config

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/app_name/*.log
  exclude_path ["/var/log/istio-*"]
  tag "kubernetes.*"
  refresh_interval 1s
  read_from_head true
  follow_inodes true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</source>
```

You can also set the filter as per requirement and push it further

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern /^my-namespace$/
  </regexp>
  <regexp>
    key $['kubernetes']['labels']['example.com/collect']
    pattern /^yes$/
  </regexp>
</filter>
```